# SED: Remove a virtual host from httpd-vhosts.conf

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to remove a virtual host item from httpd-vhosts.conf with sed, with a correct matching regex.

I want to delete a block like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.testsite.org
    DocumentRoot "/home/sites/local.testsite.org/www"
    ErrorLog "/home/sites/local.testsite.org/logs/error_log"
    CustomLog "/home/sites/local.testsite.org/logs/access_log" common
    <Directory "/home/sites/local.testsite.org/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My regex is matching it (https://regex101.com/r/Owis8w/3):

`/<VirtualHost \*:80>\n\tServerName local.duudaduu.com(.|\n)*<\/VirtualHost>/`

How do I use this expression with sed, I can't figure out how to get this working with sed...

`sed '/<VirtualHost \*:80>\n\tServerName local.testsite.org(.|\n)*<\/VirtualHost>/' /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: This is because sed doesn't naturally work with multiline pattern. There is a very counter intuitive way to make it work, but honestly, your best bet would be to use perl. More info here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-can-i-use-sed-to-replace-a-multi-line-string

Comment: Have you tried the `-r` flag?
E.g. `sed -r 's/x/y/g' $file`

Comment: @Saichovsky -r returns with 
```sed: illegal option -- r```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually abandoned this method over a much more easy way of creating and removing virtualHosts on apache using separate .conf files for every host. That way I can just create or remove a file instead of searching for a multiline string in a file.

I wanted to load a separate .conf file for every virtualhost in apache on my Mac (apache etc are installed with homebrew).

This was easy to set up in my httpd.conf. In stead of looking for a file, just look for all files in a directory with `etc/httpd/vhosts/*.conf`:

```
# Virtual hosts
# Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf  # Original rule
Include /usr/local/etc/httpd/vhosts/*.conf              # New rule
```

This looks for and includes all .conf files in that folder. My filenames are like: `local.website.com.conf`, containing something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.website.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/john/Sites/local.website.com/www"
    <Directory "/Users/john/Sites/local.website.com/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

With this approach you can simply remove a .conf file, restart apache and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

This was one of the firsts search results for this problem so in case anyone else wants to remove a VirtualHost from a .conf file with multiple such entries and not go the multiple .conf files route [described by Jurgen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922356/sed-remove-a-virtual-host-from-httpd-vhosts-conf#answer-55153208), then the answer from [this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193872/insert-remove-code-block-in-file-inside-specific-code-block-bash#answer-71207300) helped me.

Instead of `sed` you can use `awk` like this:

```
$ VHOSTS_PATH="/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
$ SERVER_NAME="local.testsite.org"
$ awk -vs='\\<ServerName[[:space:]]+'"$SERVER_NAME"'\\>' '
    /^[[:space:]]*<VirtualHost/,/^[[:space:]]*<\/VirtualHost>/ {
      tmp = tmp $0 "\n"}
    /^[[:space:]]*<\/VirtualHost>/ && tmp {
      if(tmp !~ s) printf("%s", tmp); tmp = ""; next}
    !tmp {print}' "$VHOSTS_PATH"
```