# Insert/remove code block in file inside specific code block bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to write a script which dynamically can update my local vhosts file.

Basically the idea is to add/remove a virtual host block dynamically.

1. generate vhost block dynamically ☑️
2. insert generated block into desired section of vhosts file ⚠️
3. script that can remove a virtual host by ServerName `./remove-vhost example.test` from section (pending)

My `vhosts` file looks something like this:

```sh
## Definition of all system wide vhosts, e.g.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sammy/workspace"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
# ...

## Virtual hosts inside this section should be added/removed
## dynamically
## GENERATED INCLUDES - DO NOT MODIFY ##
<VirtualHost *:80> # This host was generated automatically
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sammy/workspace/example.com"
    ServerName example.test
</VirtualHost>
# ...
## END GENERATED INCLUDES ##
```

I tried to figure out how to modify the vhosts file using `sed`.
I'm not very used to work with sed, so any assistance is well appreciated.
I tired things like

```
#!/bin/bash
# ...
VHOSTS_PATH="/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
BEGIN_OF_CODEBLOCK="## GENERATED INCLUDES - DO NOT MODIFY ##"
END_OF_CODEBLOCK="## END GENERATED INCLUDES ##"
BLOCK_TO_ADD="
<VirtualHost *:$PORT>
    DocumentRoot \"$WORKING_DIR\"
    ServerName $SERVER_NAME
</VirtualHost>"

sed "/$BEGIN_OF_CODEBLOCK/ { N; s/$BEGIN_OF_CODEBLOCK/$BLOCK_TO_ADD\n&/ }" $VHOSTS_PATH

## breaks with different errors saying e.g
# unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
```

Who could help me solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`sed` is maybe not the best tool for this. So let's use `awk` instead.  But as you ask for a `sed` solution see at the end for a `sed`-based insertion.

#### Insertion with `awk`

```sh
$ VHOSTS_PATH="/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
$ BEGIN_OF_CODEBLOCK="## GENERATED INCLUDES - DO NOT MODIFY ##"
$ BLOCK_TO_ADD="<VirtualHost *:$PORT>
    DocumentRoot \"$WORKING_DIR\"
    ServerName $SERVER_NAME
</VirtualHost>"
$ awk -vb="$BEGIN_OF_CODEBLOCK" -vi="$BLOCK_TO_ADD" '
    {print} $0 == b {print i}' "$VHOSTS_PATH"
...
## GENERATED INCLUDES - DO NOT MODIFY ##
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "foo"
    ServerName bar
</VirtualHost>
...
## END GENERATED INCLUDES ##
```

#### Deletion with `awk`

Note: this deletes any matching section, even if not in the `## GENERATED INCLUDES...` part.

```sh
$ VHOSTS_PATH="/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
$ SERVER_NAME=bar
$ awk -vs='\\<ServerName[[:space:]]+'"$SERVER_NAME"'\\>' '
    /^[[:space:]]*<VirtualHost/,/^[[:space:]]*<\/VirtualHost>/ {
      tmp = tmp $0 "\n"}
    /^[[:space:]]*<\/VirtualHost>/ && tmp {
      if(tmp !~ s) printf("%s", tmp); tmp = ""; next}
    !tmp {print}' "$VHOSTS_PATH"
...
## GENERATED INCLUDES - DO NOT MODIFY ##
<VirtualHost *:80> # This host was generated automatically
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sammy/workspace/example.com"
    ServerName example.test
</VirtualHost>
## END GENERATED INCLUDES ##
```

#### `sed`-based insertion

In such cases it is sometimes easier if you store the `sed` script itself in a shell variable:

```sh
$ VHOSTS_PATH="/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
$ BEGIN_OF_CODEBLOCK="## GENERATED INCLUDES - DO NOT MODIFY ##"
$ PORT=80
$ WORKING_DIR=foo
$ SERVER_NAME=bar
$ script='/^'"$BEGIN_OF_CODEBLOCK"'$/a \
<VirtualHost *:'"$PORT"'>\
    DocumentRoot \"'"$WORKING_DIR"'\"\
    ServerName '$SERVER_NAME'\
</VirtualHost>'
$ sed -e "$script" "$VHOSTS_PATH"
## Definition of all system wide vhosts, e.g.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sammy/workspace"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
# ...

## Virtual hosts inside this section should be added/removed
## dynamically
## GENERATED INCLUDES - DO NOT MODIFY ##
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "foo"
    ServerName bar
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80> # This host was generated automatically
    DocumentRoot "/Users/sammy/workspace/example.com"
    ServerName example.test
</VirtualHost>
# ...
## END GENERATED INCLUDES ##
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation/examples. It indeed seems that sed might not be the best solution for this. Glad you added an awk example as well.
I'll probably go take the awk approach.